# How to view Adobe Photoshop PDFs on my iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf

I'm attempting to deploy a PDF I created in Photoshop on my iPad using the PDF Pro app. When I view a text PDF, everything works flawlessly - however, when I put my image-loaded PDF on the device, it fails to load (and, if it matters, displays a completely wrong file size next to it). I'm willing to use other means, but I need to be able to view PDF's with images ASAP for a company meeting tomorrow.

How am I able to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried other apps?  iBooks or Good Reader display pdfs.

Comment: Not yet - I didn't want to keep buying apps if they don't work. Are those free?

Comment: iBooks is free, Good Reader is inexpensive, Stanza also displays PDFs and is free, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now get [Adobe Reader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-reader/id469337564?mt=8) for iPad. It is the best software for displaying everyday PDFs.

However as @Philip Regan has pointed out, Photoshop PDFs are a bit funny outside Photoshop

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop PDFs are a bit wonky even outside the iPad, and I have found it best to flatten and place them in InDesign and output a PDF from there. Even so, the iPad's PDF support is limited and searching the web for "iPad PDF viewing" yields a lot of reviews for PDF-reading applications.

In the end, however, it would be best here to have a Plan B (i.e., laptop and projector) if this so important. PDF support for the iPad still has a long way to go.